Does Istio Egress support external HTTPS proxy to transparently proxy pod's traffic?
The problem is that the traffic from the pod does not go via configured external proxy for specified sites.
There is a k8s app (node.js) that support HTTPS_PROXY environment variable, but does not support NO_PROXY. And there is a task to proxy traffic from the app to only specific sites via external proxy.
I tried to deploy the Istio egres like this:
istioctl install --set profile=minimal \
    --set values.pilot.env.PILOT_ENABLE_ALPHA_GATEWAY_API=true \
    --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=/dev/stdout \
    --set "components.egressGateways[0].name=istio-egressgateway" \
    --set "components.egressGateways[0].enabled=true" \
    --set meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode=ALLOW_ANY

And applied manifests to test traffic routing to the wikipedia via external proxy:

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - proxyext.external.site.local
  ports:
  - number: 3128
    name: http
    protocol: HTTP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: route-to-proxy
spec:
  hosts:
  - api.google.com
  - api.usa.com
  - someother.site.com
  - en.wikipedia.org
  http:
  - match:
    - port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: proxyext.external.site.local
        port:
          number: 3128

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: route-to-proxy
spec:
  gateways:
  - external-proxy-gw
  hosts:
  - "*"
  tls:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - external-proxy-gw
      port: 443
      sniHosts:
        - en.wikipedia.org
    route:
    - destination:
        host: proxyext.external.site.local
        port:
          number: 3128
      weight: 100

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: external-proxy-gw
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: tls
      protocol: TLS
    hosts:
      - en.wikipedia.org
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH


Then tried to send a request with curl to en.wikipedia.org from the container and it wasnt go via proxy, but go directly. The istio-proxy side container's log revealed this:
[2024-04-16T07:29:51.116Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 813 110483 535 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "185.15.59.224:443" outbound|443||en.wikipedia.org 10.233.103.2:32854 185.15.59.224:443 10.233.103.2:32838 en.wikipedia.org -

What am i doing wrong here?

If you are looking for controlled access for routing the requests to external service then you need to change mesh traffic to "REGISTRY_ONLY".  More details of the same can be found in istio documentation
Change the mesh attribute as below
--set meshConfig.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode=REGISTRY_ONLY

If external requests needs to be routed through an gateway then egress gateway and virtual service objects needs to be created and details are in their   istio documentation.
While installing istio if "minimal" profile is used then it wont create egress  gateway pod.  For using egress gateway you need to use "demo" profile which will install egress gateway pod.   More details of different profile are in this documentation

while i installed "minimal" profile, i've added the  --set  components.egressGateways[0].name=istio-egressgateway" --set "components.egressGateways[0].enabled=true" comman line parameters for the egress gateway pod being installed.

I deployed egress and virtual service manifests, but with no luck. I've updated my post with these manifests.

In istio-egressgateway pod log, similar access log entry.   istio documentation has explained how to route outbound traffic using gateway, virtual service, service entry and destination rule.   Please sync your manifest with proxy
